# Passing mouse and scroll events from a parent back to a child (in JavaFX)

Tags: javafx-2

I have a `StackPane` and a `Group` within it. The Group has the actual visual contents and can be panned and zoomed by the user. The Group has coordinate transformations.

I would like mouse and scroll events to behave the same even if they happen outside of the group (either because it's been zoomed out or because of holes in the Group graphics).

I cannot directly forward (mouse) events from the StackPane, since the coordinate systems differ.

I tried placing a grand transparent Rectangle behind the Group, but this leads to graphic system texture size overflows (= no good).

Now I'm thinking of having handlers in both the StackPane and the Group, passing on to coordinate-corrected separate method within the Group. Works, but would there exist a neater mechanism that I have not realized?

Comment: Does [group.setMouseTransparent(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setMouseTransparent(boolean)) help?

Comment: I don't know why the glasspane solution is not working. We are using glasspanes in our applications all over the place and they work just fine. Note that we place them in front of the group, not behind, and translate all coordinates manually and forward them to the related pieces.

Comment: I don't know of "glasspane". This is JavaFX 2.x - can you share some more info on that (but also see the way I solved it, below). Thanks.

Comment: glasspanes are a concept in UI programming. Have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

Comment: @Sebastian The problem with glasspane was that (though it was transparent) JavaFX somehow makes it a texture and there are size limits (in the GPU I guess) for textures. So it's not a bullet proof mechanism, but would use up to a certain coordinate size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this:

In the `Group` constructor I set up handlers for its parent:

```
runLater {   
  val pv= parent.value
  assert( pv != null )

  ..some local var's here..

  pv.onMousePressed = (ev: MouseEvent) => if (ev.primaryButtonDown) {
  ...
```

The `runLater` takes care that the Group does not need to be attached to its parent (or given the potential parent's handle as a constructor parameter). Once the runLater-block gets executed, the parenthood is established.

I find this a rather neat approach. It allows all the event handling to be within the Group, but still takes use of the parent's larger real estate. No code needs to be in two places. Coordinate transforms are always the same, since it's the parent's event that gets called (not the Group's).

I'm using Scala, but the same approach should work in any JVM language.

Note: Beginning the handler with an `if` would not compile in the current ScalaFX. It's a small glitch of ScalaFX and can be easily fixed (ask me for details).

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents : I got the same problem in JavaFx 8, and I solved it by replacing my Group by a Pane. No change done, and it works like a charm. Could be useful to know.